# DB2/400 SQL : "ALLOCATE" instruction

Tags: sql, db2-400

A DB2 / 400 SQL question: In the statement below, when creating a column with the "ALLOCATE" 
statement, does this mean that the database engine creates the column with an initial size of 20 Mega? 
Because the analysis of the system table indicates that the column with a column of 2G, 7M.

Does the size indicated in the "LENGHT" column correspond to the size allocated, or to the maximum size of the column ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Db2 for IBM i stores table data in two parts.

The Fixed length *row-buffer* table space and an overflow space.

If a table just has fixed length columns, all the data is in the table space.

`ALLOCATE(x)` means that the Db allocates x bytes in the table space for the column and the rest is stored in the overflow space.

The default for varying types is `allocate(0)`, so theoretically the entire varying value is store in the overflow space.

Reality is `varchar(30)` or smaller is stored in the fixed length table space for performance, unless you explicitly specify `allocate(0)`.

The reason it matters, if a query access both the fixed length table space and the overflow space, then 2 I/Os are required to retrieve all the data.

IBM recommends using an `allocate(x)` where x is large enough to handle at least 80% of values you have.

As you can see for yourself, length is the maximum size for the column.

IBM ACS's schema tool, for one example, shows you the allocated length...

```
create table mytable (
  mykey integer
  , myclob clob(200000) allocate(2000)
);
```

[image: ACS table definition screenshot]

Comment: I think thought that for large objects, It makes no sense to allocate anything because the maximum row buffer size is 32K. And, from the SQL Reference:  The allocated value may range from 1 to maximum length of the string, subject to the maximum row buffer size limit.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy 32K max row only applies if no XML or LOB... _maximum row data size is 3 758 096 383 if a LOB or XML column is specified_ per [limits](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzlimtabs.htm)

Comment: But, is that the row buffer size limit? The reason I am questioning this is that it would be strange to limit a physical record to 32K, but if you have a LOB it can be 3G. I believe the physical record size is still 32K, and the excess is stored in the variable space. I don't have enough information to determine this.

Comment: I found it [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzhctabl.htm#rbafzhctabl__rbafzmaxrcd). The maximum row buffer size is 32766 or, if a VARCHAR, VARGRAPHIC, VARBINARY, LOB, or XML column is specified, 32740. so allocate() can not allocate more than 32K even if there is a LOB or XML.

Comment: That just brings up more questions than it answers.

Comment: I think if XML or LOB, the Db uses multiple 32K row buffers for each record...up to 3G...but I'm not sure.

Comment: On my 7.2 box, I can create a table with a single integer, and a CLOB(2G) with ALLOCATE(20000), but not with ALLOCATE(40000). Oddly enough, the record length of the file is 48. Testing gets even stranger when varchars are included.